# Are shut-off valves for the tub acted via a screw?

Tags: shower, shutoff, cartridge

I need to substitute the cartridge of my pull-out shower handle that now can only be pushed back in with violent kung-fu moves. The problem is that there isn't any visible shut-off valve for the bathtub/shower as there are for the sink and the toilet and, living in a condo, I can't switch off the water to my apartment without affecting the whole column (which needs a week notice).
I had some hope that the shut-off valve was located behind the faceplate and indeed it appears to be the case. Does the screw visible in the pictures on the left of the cartridge open and close the water shut-off valve? I thought better to get some more expert opinion before starting to apply some strong torque to unstuck it. I'm used to shut-off valves with a lever control but I can imagine that behind a wall this type is more efficient. Also in this shower design, there is just a single shut-off valve for both hot and cold, correct?
Thanks

[[image: Is a shut-off valve inside the red circle?1]

[image]

Comment: I seriously doubt your valve has a shutoff. I have never seen one installed for a bath/shower combo. It doesn't mean they sometimes could be there though. Can you shut off the water just to your condo? Is your water meter independent from the other units?

Comment: This seems highly unlikely, especially the "single shutoff for hot and cold" but I'm not terribly familiar with this type of shower valve, so I'll lets someone who knows better take a crack at it. Speaking of which, what is the make/model of the shower valve in question, as you don't specify that in the question, and it likely matters.

Comment: Would be odd be have a shutoff behind/in a wall hidden.  That little valve looks more like a bleeder or adjustment screw type than a shutoff.

Comment: @Enercwal, I wish I knew. The condo complex was built in 1991 and I bought my apartment in 2004. It seems that no one knows the original equipment that was installed. From what I can tell it's a Moen shower, I would like to know the model to buy the right replacement certridge.  
@ RetiredATC, unfortunately the water can only be shut off for the whole column of 3 apartments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm surprised some of the regular posters haven't seen stops on shower valves. I've got them on mine and have worked on many showers that have them. You have to remove the trim. not all showers have them though.
Try turning those screws clockwise to turn off water. have an adjustable wrench because you might have to tighten the nut around the stems afterwards because the valves haven't been used in a long time, if ever.  Internet picture of a typical valve with stops.

[image]

Comment: It's been 14 years since I had to screw around with a shower valve, and that was wholesale replacement (old three handle) with new (single handle.) Got one coming up, but that's wholesale placement of new, and I haven't got very far on it. In both cases there are normal shutoff valves before the shower valve (because that's the way I'm wired...compartmentalize the plumbing failures/work.)

Comment: Thank you very much. There is indeed a twin valve on the other side that I had missed. Let me ask a few more question before I start working on it:
1) to close the valves I should turn both in the clockwise direction, right? There is no  weird specular symmetry 
2) If the valves present a lot of resistance, is it safe to subject them to increasingly high torque not having the possibility to shut the water off upstream? Shall I use some W40?
3) Is there any way to identify the cartridge type to get the appropriate extractor tool if I don't manage to extract it with my tools?
Thanks

Comment: @MarcoD Turn  both clockwise to turn off.  The valves shouldn't need a lot of torque, no WD40.   It looks like you have a Moen valve and the cartridge is probably a 1225 but pull the old one out to be sure. They normally come with a plastic socket type piece that fits over the stem and pushed in. You then turn it with a wrench to break the seal and then pull out the cartridge, There's a clip toward the front of the valve that has to be pulled out before you can remove the cartridge.

Comment: @MarcoD Try some CLR or some other calcium/lime remover. Those valves have probably never been operated.

Comment: @MarcoD  You're trying to turn the small stem with  the slot for a screwdriver-- right???   not the nut behind it..... Try loosening the nut turning it counterclockwise just a bit and then try the slotted stem again after some CLR.

Comment: @JACK Hey thanks for the new suggestions. I had deleted my last message because immediately after posting it, I thought f... it with my caution and I was able to actually unstuck the cold water valve by using the full power of my impact driver. That valve now closes with no damage. Unfortunately the screw of the hot valve got more stripped damaged by my previous attempts, so I’m waiting tomorrow to get a special pair of pliers from Amazon that should help me

Comment: Last night I saw those and they seem really tailored to this kind of jobs https://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/B00NBSVYOY?ref=ppx_pt2_mob_b_prod_image#

Answer (score 2):

The valves are exactly the ones you marked in red and there are two, one for cold water and one for hot water, they are located on the sides of the cartridge in order close them just turn like clock pin from left to right.TO MAKE SURE THE WATER IS CLOSED TURNS THE SHOWER HANDLE BEFORE PROCEED .

Comment: Thank you very much. There is indeed a twin valve on the other side that last night I missed because of the awkward position necessary to look in that direction at that angle. What do you mean with "pin from left to right" after instructing of turning them clockwise?

Comment: sorry I misread what you wrote. You meant a clock pin and, since I wasn’t able to move the screws, I thought you meant there was something like a security pin. Finally I was able to get the screws to relent. It took the full force of my electric impact driver. Thanks for your help!